# Experiencing a DDoS on one of my GCP instances. What can I do?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ddos

I have a single instance running on GCP which right now's suffering from a load-based DDoS. It's a Debian-based instance proxying the traffic internally to a Geneweb daemon running on the same machine.

I recognized the server only answering with 503 Service Unavailable. Which I assume is Apache still responding while the daemon just can't handle the load.

GCP's Monitoring shows the instance spike.
[GCP Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b3Nt.png)

tailf error.log shows incoming traffic.
[Screenshot Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDgFl.png)

The instance is not load-balanced and has just default firewall rules. I'm rather inexperienced in advanced network administration, which is needed here.

Any hints? Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to mitigate DDOS attacks. Check below some points that you may consider:
    1.) Reduce the attack surface for your GCE deployment
    2.) Isolate your internal traffic from the external world
    3.) DDoS Protection by enabling Proxy-based Load Balancing
    4.) Scale to absorb the attack
    5.) Protection with CDN Offloading
    6.) Deploy third-party DDoS protection solutions
    7.) App Engine deployment
    8.) Google Cloud Storage to have control access using signed URLs
    9.) API rate-limiting
    10.) Resource Quotas
For more detailed explanation check this link[1](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf) for reference.

Also I wouldn't discard that your instance got some malicious software installed that may be causing an excessive egress traffic. This is unfortunately the most common situation and it cause a huge cost increase for the affected customers due to the egress traffic.
If you think this could be the case, follow the following guidelines:
- Use the firewall rules to deny all the outgoing connections.
- Then investigate how it got compromised and analyze the behavior.
- Finally take some actions: Remove the malicious software or reinstall the VM if it would be necessary, ensure that your system is up to date and also improve its security.
Here is a more detailed guide [2](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6262505?hl=en/#gcp-compromised), about how to act on cases like this.

Also, this guide[3](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/7-tips-to-maintain-security-controls-in-your-gcp-dr-environment) can help you improve the security of your GCP enviroment.

---

Answer (score 0):

Examine the application server to determine why it is unresponsive. Many possible causes: unable to access database, hit resource limits, crashed, performance problem.

Confirm that your web server has caching on. For Apache httpd this would be from [mod_cache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/caching.html).

Put the instances behind a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/). Allows analytics on requests, and maybe scale out to more instances.

Activate a [DDoS service](https://cloud.google.com/armor/). These provide a high volume filtering service. Can be expensive at very high volume.

Look for [products in the Web Application Firewall (WAF) space](https://cloud.google.com/security/partners/). These provide advanced filtering to HTTP requests specifically. May not scale to enormous DDoS sizes, but I think your app is falling over with a relatively small number of requests.

I linked to GCP resources, but the advice applies generally.

Comment: Thx @john-mahowald. In the meantime I integrated Cloudflare as a CDN. With that I was able to get the server running again. Per Cloudflare's analysis the attack comes from China.